# Where should I manually add subviews when using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, visual-format-language

I'm trying to force myself to start using AutoLayout everywhere. I have a scenario that is extremely simple using frames but I can't make it work using Autolayout.

I have a StoryBoard I can't touch because it belongs to a library. When the ViewController related to the storyboard loads I want to programmatically add a View. So I created a `UIView` in the `viewDidLoad`, added the constraints for height and width and also two other constraints to position them. Everything worked fine BUT the width, I want to have the same width as an other view. How should I do this?

I logged the size of the "other view" in the `viewDidLoad` and the size is not right, I also logged the `self.view.frame.size.width`, and is not correct either.

I read that the correct sizes are not set until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so I tried to add my code there but I get in a loop of calls to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that never ends. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the code in `viewDidAppear`.  Check if the subview is already a descendent of the view and if no, then add the subview with the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you want two views to have the same width, you should do that with 
`constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`. You can do this in viewDidLoad.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *widthCon = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
```

This assumes that the view that comes from the library storyboard was made using constraints.

Comment: This works even if the library storyboard was not made using constraints. That's not a requirement.

Comment: @KenThomases would it work in `viewDidLoad` if that view were not made with auto layout? I wasn't sure, in that case, if the width would be properly set at that time.

Comment: This doesn't rely on the view's width being set at any particular time. You're establishing a mathematical relationship between the widths of the the two views (that they are equal). Auto layout maintains that relationship over time. Assuming nothing other than this constraint imposes a width on `view1`, then its width will be changed to `view2`'s width when layout is performed. `view2`'s width may be a consequence of other explicit constraints if the library storyboard using auto layout, or it may be a consequence of constraints automatically derived springs-and-struts mechanism, if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use this method of UIViewController's,

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints 
{
   [super updateViewConstraints] ;

   // now update your subviews contraints or log your view sizes

}
```

*As you are using constraint based layout and wants to update the subviews constraints depending to UIViewController's constraints then you should always use the following method.*